# Julia - Parallelism for Reading a Large file

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia

In Julia v1.1, assume that I have a very large text file (30GB) and I want parallelism (multi-threads) to read eachline, how can I do ?

This code is an attempt to do this after checking [Julia's documentation on multi-threading](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/index.html#Multi-Threading-(Experimental)-1), but it's not working at all

```
open("pathtofile", "r") do file
    # Count number of lines in file
    seekend(file)
    fileSize = position(file)
    seekstart(file)

    # skip nseekchars first characters of file
    seek(file, nseekchars)

    # progress bar, because it's a HUGE file
    p = Progress(fileSize, 1, "Reading file...", 40)
    Threads.@threads for ln in eachline(file)
        # do something on ln
        u, v = map(x->parse(UInt32, x), split(ln))
        .... # other interesting things
        update!(p, position(file))
    end    
end
```

Note 1 : you need `using ProgressMeter` (I want my code to show a progress bar while parallelism the file reading)

Note 2 : nseekchars is an Int and the number of characters I want to skip in the beginning in my file

Note 3 : the code is working but doesn't do parellelism without `Threads.@threads` macro next to the for loop

Comment: Reading a file is not CPU intensive, so parallelising it will not result in a performance improvement. Storing it on a striped disk array would.

Comment: @ııı Thanks, I don't know about striped disk array, is this what you are talking about ? https://github.com/JuliaParallel/Blocks.jl unfortunately, Blocks don't seem to be available for julia v1.1

Comment: I think he talks about raid 0 or similar

Comment: @sascha alright, this is quite new for me is there something linked to this on Julia ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the maximum I/O performance:

1. Parallelize the hardware - that is use disk arrays rather than a single drive. Try searching for *raid performance* for many excellent explanations (or ask a separate question)
2. Use the Julia [memory mapping](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.1/stdlib/Mmap/) mechanism

```
s = open("my_file.txt","r")
using Mmap
a = Mmap.mmap(s)
```

3. Once having the memory mapping, do the processing in parallel. Beware of [false sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593588/julia-why-doesnt-shared-memory-multi-threading-give-me-a-speedup) for threads (depends on your actual scenario).