# Multi threading for reading CSV Files in Julia

Tags: multithreading, csv, julia

Is there a way to implement multi-threading on `CSV.read` in Julia? A good example to read big files has been presented in [Parallelism for reading a large file in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874366/julia-parallelism-for-reading-a-large-file).
But since I have to frequently change my datasets these approaches may not be applicable.

```
using CSV
file = ("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Datasets\\X_train_sat4.csv")
@time df = CSV.read(file, DataFrame)

Output:
69.469112 seconds (6.29 M allocations: 9.767 GiB, 0.76% gc time)
29723 rows × 2456 columns
```

I have used the steps recommended here [Speed up loading and compilation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65660180/read-csv-files-faster-in-julia) but these improves only the first loading time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV.jl supports multi-threading. You can select how many threads you want to use with `tasks` keyword argument. You cannot use more than number of threads that your Julia process was started with.

Here is a sample timing on reading a file having 10^8 rows and 10 columns:

```
julia> @time CSV.read("test.csv", DataFrame, ntasks=1); # one thread
 75.190387 seconds (23.24 M allocations: 9.253 GiB, 1.24% gc time)

julia> @time CSV.read("test.csv", DataFrame, ntasks=2); # two threads
 43.078513 seconds (4.34 M allocations: 8.044 GiB, 2.30% gc time)
```

By default number of tasks used is set to `Threads.nthreads()`.