# julia multi-threaded not scaling for embarrassingly parallel job

Tags: multithreading, julia, scaling

The following code calculates the average number of draws to get 50 unique cards from several sets. All what is important is that this problem does not require much RAM and does not share any variable when launched in multi-threading mode. When launched with four more than one thread to perform 400,000 simulations it consistently takes about an extra second than two processes launched together and performing 200,000 simulations. This has been bothering me and I could not find any explanation.

This is the Julia code in epic_draw_multi_thread.jl:

```julia
using Random
using Printf
import Base.Threads.@spawn

function pickone(dist)
    n = length(dist)
    i = 1
    r = rand()
    while r >= dist[i] && i<n 
        i+=1
    end
    return i
end  

function init_items(type_dist, unique_elements)
    return zeros(Int32, length(type_dist), maximum(unique_elements))
end

function draw(type_dist, unique_elements_dist)
    item_type = pickone(type_dist)
    item_number = pickone(unique_elements_dist[item_type])
    return item_type, item_number
end

function draw_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, items, x)
    while sum(items .> 0) < x
        item_type, item_number = draw(type_dist, unique_elements_dist)
        items[item_type, item_number] += 1
    end
    return sum(items)
end

function average_for_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, x, n, reset=true)
    println(@sprintf("Started average_for_unique on thread %d with n = %d", Threads.threadid(), n))
    items = init_items(type_dist, unique_elements)

    tot_draws = 0
    for i in 1:n
        tot_draws += draw_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, items, x)
        if reset
            items .= 0
        else
            items[items.>1] -= 1
        end
    end

    println(@sprintf("Completed average_for_unique on thread %d with n = %d", Threads.threadid(), n))
    return tot_draws / n
end

function parallel_average_for_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, x, n, reset=true)
    println("Started computing...")
    t = max(Threads.nthreads() - 1, 1)
    m = Int32(round(n / t))
    tasks = Array{Task}(undef, t)
    @sync for i in 1:t
        task = @spawn average_for_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, x, m)
        tasks[i] = task
    end
    sum(fetch(t) for t in tasks) / t
end
    
type_dist = [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.05]
const cum_type_dist = cumsum(type_dist)

unique_elements = [21, 27, 32, 14, 10]
unique_elements_dist = [[1 / unique_elements[j] for i in 1:unique_elements[j]] for j in 1:length(unique_elements)]
const cum_unique_elements_dist = [cumsum(dist) for dist in unique_elements_dist]

str_n = ARGS[1]
n = parse(Int64, str_n)
avg = parallel_average_for_unique(cum_type_dist, cum_unique_elements_dist, 50, n)
print(avg)
```

This is the command issued at the shell to run on two threads along with the output and timing results:

```
time julia --threads 3 epic_draw_multi_thread.jl 400000
Started computing...
Started average_for_unique on thread 3 with n = 200000
Started average_for_unique on thread 2 with n = 200000
Completed average_for_unique on thread 2 with n = 200000
Completed average_for_unique on thread 3 with n = 200000
70.44460749999999
real    0m14.347s
user    0m26.959s
sys     0m2.124s
```

These are the command issued at the shell to run two processes with half the job size each along with the output and timing results:

```
time julia --threads 1 epic_draw_multi_thread.jl 200000 &
time julia --threads 1 epic_draw_multi_thread.jl 200000 &
Started computing...
Started computing...
Started average_for_unique on thread 1 with n = 200000
Started average_for_unique on thread 1 with n = 200000
Completed average_for_unique on thread 1 with n = 200000
Completed average_for_unique on thread 1 with n = 200000
70.434375
real    0m12.919s
user    0m12.688s
sys     0m0.300s
70.448695
real    0m12.996s
user    0m12.790s
sys     0m0.308s
```

No matter how many times I repeat the experiment, I always get the multi-threaded mode slower.
Notes:

1. I created parallel code to approximate the value of PI and did not
   experience the same problem. However, I do not see anything in this
   code that could cause any conflict between threads causing slowness.
2. When started with more than one thread, I use the number of threads minus one to perform the draws. Failing that, the last thread seems to hang on. This statement `t = max(Threads.nthreads() - 1, 1)` can be changed to `t = Threads.nthreads()` to use the exact number of threads available.

**EDIT on 11/20/2020**

Implemented Przemyslaw Szufel recommendations. This is the new code:

```julia
using Random
using Printf
import Base.Threads.@spawn
using BenchmarkTools

function pickone(dist, mt)
    n = length(dist)
    i = 1
    r = rand(mt)
    while r >= dist[i] && i<n 
        i+=1
    end
    return i
end  

function init_items(type_dist, unique_elements)
    return zeros(Int32, length(type_dist), maximum(unique_elements))
end

function draw(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, mt)
    item_type = pickone(type_dist, mt)
    item_number = pickone(unique_elements_dist[item_type], mt)
    return item_type, item_number
end

function draw_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, items, x, mt)
    while sum(items .> 0) < x
        item_type, item_number = draw(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, mt)
        items[item_type, item_number] += 1
    end
    return sum(items)
end

function average_for_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, x, n, mt, reset=true)
    println(@sprintf("Started average_for_unique on thread %d with n = %d", Threads.threadid(), n))
    items = init_items(type_dist, unique_elements)

    tot_draws = 0
    for i in 1:n
        tot_draws += draw_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, items, x, mt)
        if reset
            items .= 0
        else
            items[items.>1] -= 1
        end
    end

    println(@sprintf("Completed average_for_unique on thread %d with n = %d", Threads.threadid(), n))
    return tot_draws / n
end

function parallel_average_for_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, x, n, reset=true)
    println("Started computing...")
    t = max(Threads.nthreads() - 1, 1)
    mts = MersenneTwister.(1:t)
    m = Int32(round(n / t))
    tasks = Array{Task}(undef, t)
    @sync for i in 1:t
        task = @spawn average_for_unique(type_dist, unique_elements_dist, x, m, mts[i])
        tasks[i] = task
    end
    sum(fetch(t) for t in tasks) / t
end
    
type_dist = [0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.05]
const cum_type_dist = cumsum(type_dist)

unique_elements = [21, 27, 32, 14, 10]
unique_elements_dist = [[1 / unique_elements[j] for i in 1:unique_elements[j]] for j in 1:length(unique_elements)]
const cum_unique_elements_dist = [cumsum(dist) for dist in unique_elements_dist]

str_n = ARGS[1]
n = parse(Int64, str_n)
avg = @btime parallel_average_for_unique(cum_type_dist, cum_unique_elements_dist, 50, n)
print(avg)
```

Updated benchmarks:

```
Threads          @btime     Linux Time       
1 (2 processes)  9.927 s    0m44.871s 
2 (1 process)   20.237 s    1m14.156s
3 (1 process)   14.302 s    1m2.114s
```

Comment: What version of Julia is that?  What operating system?  I can't reproduce your issue (multithreading _slower_ than single threads) with any of Julia v1.3, v1.4, v1.5, v1.6 on Linux.  For me multithreading is always faster than single thread, even though it doesn't fully scale (it's about 2.2x faster with 4 Julia threads -> 3 threads in your code)

Comment: I am using version 1.5.2

Comment: The  code reads a bit Fortranesque to me -- there's a lot of things done manually. For example, do you know about Distributions.jl?

Comment: @phipsgabler Yes, I know about Distributions.jl. However, I want to draw values until a condition is met and therefore do not know how many random numbers I need to generate in advance. There are n decks of cards containing different numbers of cards each. I randomly select a deck, then randomly select a card from that deck. I continue doing so until I get x distinct cards. Any idea on how to do that better? All the cards in the different decks are different and the probabilities to pick a deck or another are different.

Comment: [Weighted reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Weighted_random_sampling), perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems here:

1. You are not measuring the performance correctly
2. When generating random numbers in threads you should have a separate `MersenneTwister` random state for each thread for the best performance (otherwise your random state is shared across all threads and synchronization needs to occur)

Currently you are measuring the time of "Julia starting time" + "code compile time" + "runtime". Compilation of a multi-threaded code obviously takes longer than compilation of a single-threaded code. And starting Julia itself also takes a second or two.

You have two option here. The easiest is to use `BenchmarkTools` `@btime` macro to measure execution times inside the code.
Another option would be to make your code into a package and compile it into a Julia image via [PackageCompiler](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl). You will be still however measuring "Julia start time" + "Julia execution time"

The random number state could be created as:

```
mts = MersenneTwister.(1:Threads.nthreads());
```

and then used such as `rand(mts[Threads.threadid()])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code is exactly the same and is therefore compiled the same way. I will have a look at the `MersenneTwister`, although as said in the note, I generated many random numbers when approximating PI and did not face the same problem. Finally, even with the approx measurement method from the command line, I consistently have a longer runtime with multi-threading. I will have a look at your recommendations though.

Comment: In many practical cases I have seen a single threaded code to take 1s to compile and the same muti-threaded code to take 5s. Maybe try running your benchmark on code that takes over 30s to run?

Comment: Your answer about the random generator is probably correct. As per https://discourse.julialang.org/t/multi-threading/22708 the behavior of rand() when called from different threads is undefined. Maybe it has been modified to include synchronization which could explain the extra time with threads bumping into each other to get a random number. The question is now: How to efficiently generate random numbers from different threads?

Comment: It has been updated to include synchronization. But still if a single state is shared as far as I remember they are still bumping into each other. "How to efficiently generate random numbers from different threads?" -> it was already in my post.

Comment: Oops, did not properly read your post. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: OK, I implemented all your recommendations and still get the same behavior. See updated code and benchmarks. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you might be running into false sharing - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593588/julia-why-doesnt-shared-memory-multi-threading-give-me-a-speedup